# Finding the compound interest. Task from the Elements of Algebra by L. Euler

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A trader allows 100$.per annum for the  expenses  of his  family, and  yearly augments  that part of his  stock which is  not so  expended, by a third part of it; at the end  of three  years, his  original stock was  doubled:  what had he at first?

I came up with equation $(1/3)^3 - (1/3)^2*100 - 1/3*100 - 100 = 2a$. But this equation doesn't work when I try to calculate this thing. I think I misunderstood the exercise. I'd appreciate some help

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please add some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/90543) to your question. As it is now, all that is in the post is Euler's question, but it's unclear what your question is. Are you asking what the question means when it is translated out of archaic English? Are you asking how to solve this question? If you are asking how to solve the question, where are you getting stuck? It is difficult for us to help you without knowing where you are having problems.

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question. Hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S_n$ be the trader's starting stock in year $n$. As I understand the archaic English, it says that every year, the trader's stock at the end of the year is given by the equation
$$S_{n+1}=\frac{4}{3}(S_n-100).$$

Thus what we are being asked is if $S_3=2S_0$, what is $S_0$?

Then expanding $S_3$ out, we get 
$$S_3=\frac{4}{3}(S_2-100)=\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}(S_1-100)-100\right)=\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}(S_0-100)-100\right)-100\right),$$
or $$27S_3 = 64S_0-64\cdot 100 - 16\cdot 3\cdot 100 - 4\cdot 9\cdot 100$$
$$=64S_0-6400-4800-3600$$
$$=64S_0-14800.$$
Substituting $S_3=2S_0$, we get
$$54S_0=64S_0-14800,$$
or $10S_0=14800$. Thus $S_0=1480$.

Indeed, this yields $S_1=\frac{4}{3}\cdot 1380 = 1840$, $S_2=\frac{4}{3}\cdot 1740=2320$,
and $S_3= \frac{4}{3} \cdot 2220=2960=2\cdot 1480$, as desired.